# iterating dynamic key in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview

I am having a response as follows

```
    {
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "store 1": [
      {
        "id": 27,
        "cart_id": 5,
        "item": {
          "id": 35,
          "name": "test prod 1"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 28,
        "cart_id": 56,
        "item": {
          "id": "jk",
          "name": "test prod 2"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 27,
        "cart_id": 5,
        "item": {
          "id": 35,
          "name": "test prod 1"
        }
      }
    ],
    "store 2": [
      {
        "id": 27,
        "cart_id": 5,
        "item": {
          "id": 35,
          "name": "test prod 1"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 28,
        "cart_id": 56,
        "item": {
          "id": "jk",
          "name": "test prod 2"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 27,
        "cart_id": 5,
        "item": {
          "id": 35,
          "name": "test prod 1"
        }
      }
    ],
    "store 3": [
      {
        "id": 27,
        "cart_id": 5,
        "item": {
          "id": 35,
          "name": "test prod 1"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 28,
        "cart_id": 56,
        "item": {
          "id": "jk",
          "name": "test prod 2"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 27,
        "cart_id": 5,
        "item": {
          "id": 35,
          "name": "test prod 1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

here is how i am itreating the value in api response

```
 if (response.data['success'] == true) {
      
      Map mapValue = jsonDecode(response.data);
 
      List<ShoppingCartModel> cartList = [];
      mapValue['data'].forEach((key, value) {
        List<Store> store = [];
        value.forEach((item) {
          store.add(Store(
              id: item['id'],
              cartid: item['cart_id'],
              product: item['product']));
        });
        cartList.add(ShoppingCartModel(sname: key, storeList: store));
      });
     
      print(cartList);
      return cartList;
```

here is my model

```
class ShoppingCartModel {
  String sname;
  List<Store> storeList;

  ShoppingCartModel({this.sname, this.storeList});

  ShoppingCartModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    sname = json['sname'];
    storeList =
        List<Store>.from(json["storeList"].map((x) => Store.fromJson(x)));
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['sname'] = this.sname;

    data['storeList'] = List<dynamic>.from(storeList.map((x) => x.toJson()));

    return data;
  }
}

class Store {
  int id;
  int cartid;
  Item item;

  Store({this.id, this.cartid, this.item});

  Store.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    cartid = json['cart_id'];
    item = Item.fromJson(json["item"]);
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['cart_id'] = this.cartid;
    data['item'] = item.toJson();

    return data;
  }
}

class Item {
  int id;
  String name;
 

  Item({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    
  });

  Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    //price = json['price'].toDouble();
  
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
   

    return data;
  }
}
```

Here is part of my code in view

```
return ListView(
                        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            child: Column(
                              children: List.generate(shoppingCartData.length,
                                  (index) {
                                return _buildStoreName(index, boxImageSize);
                              }),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      );
                    }


                    Column _buildStoreName(index, boxImageSize) {
    //int quantity = shoppingCartData[index].qty;
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          child: Container(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  shoppingCartData[index].sname,
                  style: GlobalStyle.productName.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                  maxLines: 3,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    children: List.generate(
                        shoppingCartData[index].storeList.length, (indexStore) {
                      return _buildItem(shoppingCartData[index].storeList,
                          indexStore, boxImageSize);
                    }),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }


  Column _buildItem(cartdata, indexStore, boxImageSize) {
    int quantity = cartdata[indexStore].item.quantity;
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          child: Container(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    
                  
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                         
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          cartdata[indexStore].item.name,
                          style: GlobalStyle.productName.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                          maxLines: 3,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
                      ),
                      
                     
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
              )
      ],
    );
  }
```

here is my required view

[image]

i am getting error while mapping itself.Just the store name are different but the keys inside are same

I need to iterate first list as store and second list as iem values in a list view

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the `response.data` as map before you `decode` it.

Try `jsonDecode()` before this condition

`if (response.data['success'] == true)`

Example:

```
var res = jsonDecode(response.data);
if(res['success'] == true){
    // do rest of your operation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) package for this code:

**products_data.dart**

```
const String productData = '''
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
  ...
  }
}
''';
```

**item_model.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class ItemModel {
  dynamic id;
  String name;

  ItemModel({@required this.id, @required this.name});

  ItemModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    id = data['id'];
    name = data['name'];
  }
}
```

**asset_model.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:getx_json/models/item_model.dart';

class AssetModel {
  int id;
  int cartId;
  ItemModel item;

  AssetModel({@required this.id, @required this.cartId, @required this.item});

  AssetModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    id = data['id'];
    cartId = data['cart_id'];
    item = ItemModel.fromJson(data['item']);
  }

  Card showCard() => Card(
    color: Colors.lightBlue,
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text('id: $id'),
        Text('cart_id: $cartId'),
        Text('Item', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
            child: Card(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text('id: ${item.id}'),
                  Text('name: ${item.name}'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

**shopping_controller.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:getx_json/models/asset_model.dart';
import 'package:getx_json/src/shared/products_data.dart';

class ShoppingController extends GetxController {
  var assets = Map<String, List<AssetModel>>().obs;

  @override
  void onInit(){
    super.onInit();
    fetchProducts();
  }

  void fetchProducts() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    Map<String, dynamic> response = jsonDecode(productData);

    if (response['success'] == true) {
      var data = Map<String, List<AssetModel>>();

      (response['data'] as Map<String, dynamic>).forEach((key, value) {
        data[key] = (value as List).map((e) => AssetModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
      });
      
      assets.addAll(data);
    }
  }
}
```

**home_page.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:getx_json/src/controllers/shopping_controller.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
  const HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final stores = Get.put(ShoppingController());

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child:
          Obx(() => stores.assets.length > 0 ? buildListView() : buildText()),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildListView() {
    final stores = Get.find<ShoppingController>().assets;
    final titles = stores.keys.toList();

    return ListView.builder(
      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      itemCount: stores.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
        color: Colors.orange,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(titles[index], style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              ListView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: stores[titles[index]].length,
                itemBuilder: (context, idx) => stores[titles[index]][idx].showCard(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildText() {
    final stores = Get.find<ShoppingController>();

    return Text(stores.assets.toString());
  }
}
```